# TikZ/PGF: compilation hangs when using macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, fpu

When compiling the following code using `pdflatex`,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\dim#1{
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
    \pgfmathparse{#1}
    \pgfmathresult pt
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
}
\draw ( 0, \dim{10in + 1in} ) circle (1in);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the compilation hangs at the following lines:

```
[...]
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
```

Where exactly is the problem? Why does the compilation hang?

Basically, I'd like to have a TeX macro that parses the first argument using PGF's FPU, then returns its result in `pt`s.

**EDIT:** I'm using texlive 20120701 and PGF 2.10

---

I noticed that this issue is not related to the macro at all. The following code fails the same way:

```
\draw ( 0,
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
    \pgfmathparse{sqrt(pow(10in, 2) + pow(12in, 2))}
    \pgfmathresult pt
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
) circle (1in);
```

Comment: `\draw ( 0, {(10in + 1in)} ) circle (1in);` is enough to parse.

Comment: Yes it is, but I need to use PGF's FPU. I know, my example isn't ideal, I should've used something like `\dim{sqrt(pow(10in, 2) + pow(12in, 2))}` to demonstrate the actual problem (use the same expression in TeX and you'll get the `Dimension too large` error when compiling).

Comment: At a guess, I'd be worrying about expandability here.  Are all the macros in `\dim` expandable?  (Also, note that `\dim` is already defined in the LaTeX kernel so you might want to choose another name.)

Comment: @AndrewStacey, this might indeed be the reason. Unfortunately I can not figure out what is expandable and what not.

Comment: Ah cool haha a simpler example `\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,\pgfkeys{}) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}`. It's meant to be a hint :P

Comment: As each part of a coordinate is expanded using `\edef` an even simpler example is `\edef{\pgfkeys{}}`.

Comment: @percusse, alright, it seems to be obvious now :). Thank you. I noticed that `\pgfmathparse` isn't necessary at all - if I just use `\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed] ... \end{tikzpicture}`, calculations like in `\draw ( 0, {sqrt(pow(10in,2)+pow(12in,2))} ) circle (1);` work out of the box...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just throw any old command into a `tikz` coordinate as each `x`, `y` (o `z`) component is expanded using `\edef`. One could try defining a special coordinate system (note in the example below, unit-less dimensions will be interpreted as points).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\tikzset{fpu cs/.cd, x/.initial=0, y/.initial=0}

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{fpu}{%
\tikzset{fpu cs/.cd,#1}%
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
  \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fpu cs/x}}%
  \let\tmpx=\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fpu cs/y}}%
  \let\tmpy=\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfpoint{+\tmpx pt}{+\tmpy pt}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (fpu cs:x=0, y={sqrt(pow(10in, 2) + pow(12in, 2))}) circle [radius=1in];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Not much point in showing the output as it is just a circle. You could of course add the `fpu` options to the `tikzpicture` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. So now I'm just using `/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed` as options for `tikzpicture` and everything works as expected. No need to use `\pgfmathparse`/`\pgfmathresult` anymore, as all calculations are now done using PGF's FPU.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if next code is useful but works in this case

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand\mydim[2]{
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{#1}{#2}
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
}

\draw ( 0, {(10in + 1in)} ) circle (1in);

\mydim{\test}{sqrt(pow(10in,2)+pow(12in,2))}
\draw ( 0, \test ) circle (1in);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work, thank you. But it is a little bit inconvenient. I wonder why it won't work with `\pgfmathparse`, it seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @watain It's ***not*** a bug. TikZ wants to see an expression, not the instructions to produce an expression and that involve assignments (such as `\pgfmathparse`).